# Binary Search using Comparator

Tags: java, comparator, binary-search, functor

I'm struggling to get this to work. I need to write a functor that will work with a binarySearch algorithm to find a ladder that has a length between 12 and 15 units.

Here's the binary search:

```
public static <AnyType> int binarySearch(GenericSimpleArrayList<AnyType> a, AnyType x, Comparator<? super AnyType> cmp) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.size() - 1;
    int mid;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (cmp.compare(a.get(mid), x) < 0) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else if (cmp.compare(a.get(mid), x) > 0) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return NOT_FOUND; // NOT_FOUND = -1
}
```

and here's what I have for the functor:

```
public class FindLadder implements Comparator<Ladder>{

  @Override
  public int compare(Ladder lhs, Ladder rhs) {
    return 0;
}

}
```

Now obviously, the functor won't do anything at the moment, I don't know what to put in the functor in order to determine if a ladder falls between x and x length, nor do I know how to implement the binarySearch method. I would need to pass a Ladder object as x in order for the functor to work, as far as I can tell, but then how do I stipulate the length that I am searching for? The Ladder class has a .length() method.

The array is sorted in the order of shortest to longest. I cannot change the binarySearch code at all. I can only implement a functor that will do what I need.

Comment: Any search method that would need to find something between `A` and `B` would by its very nature need to know both `A` and `B`, i.e. the lower and upper boundary. Your search method takes only 1 `x`, so how can you tell it the two numbers `12` and `15`?

Comment: @Andreas well this is where I'm struggling. I can see no possible way to do it. I can hard-code it since I know the position of the ladder that I'm looking for, but apparently something can be done in the Functor to avoid this.

Comment: @SarahvdByl I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class FindLadder implements Comparator<Ladder>{
  @Override
  public int compare(Ladder lhs, Ladder rhs) {
    if(lhs.length() < rhs.length() && lhs.length() > 12) // Suppose rhs.length() is 15
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(lhs.length() < 12) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Invoke `binarySearch()` with x = 15. Like `LibraryComparator.binarySearch(l, new Ladder(15), new FindLadder());`

I hard-coded `12`. There's no other way.

Comment: Alright, I have another similar functor class that does the same thing. How would I call the binarySearch method while also applying the criteria that I need?

Comment: I'm not sure that's right. The possible return values are `-1`, `0`, `1`.

Comment: @SarahvdByl I can't get what u r saying?

Comment: @Saud For example, in my main method I currently have `LibraryComparator.binarySearch(l, 15, new Length());` which does not work. I don't know how to specify that I am searching for a ladder between 12 and 15 units long.

Comment: For that, I can't think of anything except editing the binarySearch() method (which ain't an option).

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Return value is [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) as "negative integer, zero, or positive integer". Doesn't have to be `-1`, `0`, `1`, any integer will do.

Comment: @SarahvdByl your `binarySearch` method has only one parameter `x` with which it compares other ladders. If you want to get a ladder within a specific range, you need two paramenters `x` and `y`.

Comment: @Saud invoking it this way doesn't work, unfortunately. It gives the error "Inference variable AnyType out of bounds." I think this is due to the compare method requiring two Ladder objects as opposed to a Ladder object and an integer.

Comment: There is another way, see my answer

Answer (score 3):

## Short version by hacking Collections.binarySearch

> The framework has [built-in binary search](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)) and [generic `List<T>` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), you should use them.

The built-in `binarySearch` function always supplies the pivot element to the comparator as the second argument. This is undocumented behaviour, but we can exploit that, using the following comparator:

```
public static class FindLadderInterval implements Comparator<Ladder> {
  public final int min, max;
  public FindLadderInterval(int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
  }
  @Override
  public int compare(Ladder lhs, Ladder rhs) {
    // ignore rhs
    int length = lhs.length();
    return length < this.min ? -1 : length > this.max ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, null, new FindLadderInterval(12, 15));
```

Working example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main2 {

  public static class Ladder {
    private final int _length;

    public Ladder(int length) {
      this._length = length;
    }

    public int length() {
      return this._length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Ladder(" + this._length + ")";
    }
  }

  public static class FindLadderInterval implements Comparator<Ladder> {
    public final int min, max;

    public FindLadderInterval(int min, int max) {
      this.min = min;
      this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Ladder lhs, Ladder rhs) {
      // ignore rhs
      int length = lhs.length();
      return length < this.min ? -1 : length > this.max ? 1 : 0;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Ladder> list = new ArrayList<Ladder>();

    list.add(new Ladder(1));
    list.add(new Ladder(2));
    list.add(new Ladder(6));
    list.add(new Ladder(13));
    list.add(new Ladder(17));
    list.add(new Ladder(21));

    int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, null,
        new FindLadderInterval(12, 15));
    System.out.println("index: " + index);
    System.out.println("ladder: " + list.get(index));
  }
}
```

## Long version using proper algorithms

Your task to find an element in an interval is not a simple binary search, but we can implement it using a `binarySearch` function similar to the built-in one, because that returns the *insertion index* as a negative number if the element was not found. So we can search for the element at the end of the interval, if it's found then return it, and if it's not found simply check if the item at the insertion index is in the interval, and return that. This way the algorithm will return the last element in the interval.

```
public static <T, R extends Comparable<? super R>> int intervalBinarySearchBy(
    List<T> list, R min, R max, Function<? super T, ? extends R> selector) {
  int idx = binarySearchBy(list, max, selector);
  if (idx >= 0) return idx;
  // Collections.binarySearch returns the insertion index binary
  // negated if the element was not found
  idx = ~idx;
  return (idx < list.size()
    && min.compareTo(selector.apply(list.get(idx))) <= 0) ? idx : -1;
}
```

To use the built-in `Collections.binarySearch` or your function, you need to provide a *representative element*, which is pretty hard when for example you order strings by their lengths. To find a string with a length of 15 you must provide a string with length of 15. That's why I like the python style ordering much more, which uses *key functions* or *selectors*. Basically, you don't need comparisons but a mapping to a comparable value. For example a mapping from `String` to `Integer` like `s -> s.length()`. This makes possible to implement sweet functions like these (lambdas make it pretty):

```
List<Person> list = getPersons();
Person youngest = minBy(list, p -> p.getAge());
Person tallest = maxBy(list, p -> p.getHeight());
Person person42 = findBy(list, 42, p -> p.getAge());
sortBy(list, p -> p.getAge());
```

See, don't need a `Comparator` to order items by a property. Simple task, simple solution. Unfortunately, I am not aware of functions like this in either the standard library or third-parties. But they can be implemented.

A working example in Java 8:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {

  public static class Collections2 {

    /**
     * Mimics Collections.binarySearch
     * 
     * @param list
     * @param pivotKey
     * @param selector
     * @return
     */
    public static <T, R extends Comparable<? super R>> int binarySearchBy(
        List<T> list, R pivotKey,
        Function<? super T, ? extends R> selector) {
      int low = 0;
      int high = list.size() - 1;
      while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        int ord = selector.apply(list.get(mid)).compareTo(pivotKey);
        if (ord < 0) {
          low = mid + 1;
        } else if (ord > 0) {
          high = mid - 1;
        } else {
          return mid;
        }
      }
      return ~high; // bitwise negated insertion point /* -(a+1) == ~a */
    }

    /**
     * Finds the index of the last element in the interval, or returns -1 if
     * no such element was found.
     * 
     * @param list
     * @param min
     * @param max
     * @param selector
     * @return
     */
    public static <T, R extends Comparable<? super R>> int intervalBinarySearchBy(
        List<T> list, R min, R max, Function<? super T, ? extends R> selector) {
      int idx = binarySearchBy(list, max, selector);
      if (idx >= 0) return idx;
      // Collections.binarySearch returns the insertion index binary
      // negated if the element was not found
      idx = ~idx;
      return (idx < list.size()
        && min.compareTo(selector.apply(list.get(idx))) <= 0) ? idx : -1;
    }

    public static <T, R extends Comparable<? super R> > Comparator<T> comparatorBy(
        Function<? super T, ? extends R> selector) {
      return (a, b) -> selector.apply(a).compareTo(selector.apply(b));
    }
  }

  public static Function<Ladder, Integer> LENGTH_OF = a -> a.length();

  public static class Ladder {
    private final int _length;

    public Ladder(int length) {
      this._length = length;
    }

    public int length() {
      return this._length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Ladder(" + this._length + ")";
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Ladder> list = new ArrayList<Ladder>();
    list.add(new Ladder(5));
    list.add(new Ladder(9));
    list.add(new Ladder(14));
    list.add(new Ladder(7));
    list.add(new Ladder(22));
    list.add(new Ladder(23));
    list.add(new Ladder(11));
    list.add(new Ladder(9));

    Collections.sort(list, Collections2.comparatorBy(LENGTH_OF));

    int i = 0;
    for (Ladder s : list) {
      System.out.println("" + (i++) + ": " + s);
    }

    int foundIdx = Collections2.intervalBinarySearchBy(list, 12, 15,
        LENGTH_OF);
    System.out.println("Index: " + foundIdx);
    System.out.println(list.get(foundIdx));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You obviously want/need to implement your own binary search, but let me reference the built-in method anyway.

From javadoc of [Collections.binarySearch(List, T, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

> Returns the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise, `(-(insertion point) - 1)`. The *insertion point* is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: the index of the first element greater than the key, or `list.size()` if all elements in the list are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

The key here is the *insertion point*, or said another way, the returned index points to the first element that is >= the search value, or `size()` if no such element exists. There is no `NOT_FOUND` return value.

Since you want a value between `12` and `15`, search for `12`, then verify that you found an value and that the value is <= `15`.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the preconditions of binarySearch algorithm:

- The items must be stored in ascending order in advance.
- You must provide an item with the features to be found.

Then try this

```
public int compare(Ladder lhs, Ladder rhs) {
    boolean isLhsInRange = lhs.length() >= 12 && lhs.length() <= 15;
    boolean isRhsInRange = rhs.length() >= 12 && rhs.length() <= 15;
    if(isLhsInRange && isRhsInRange) return 0;
    else return lhs.length() - rhs.length();
}
```